# Install switch to disable airbag in 2003 Chrysler Town & Country

Tags: chrysler, supplemental-restraint-system

I heard that it was possible to install a switch in a 2003 Town & Country to disable the airbag.

We called several auto shops, who said they don't do it.
We called Chrysler, who said they only heard of it being done in pickup trucks.

Is it possible, and how/where to get it done, to install a switch to disable the air bag in a 2003 Chrysler Town & Country?

Comment: Which airbag are you trying to disable? I have not heard of doing this for the driver's side. Some vehicles have a switch in the seat which senses if there is weight in it. If too much weight, it trips the airbag on, if not, it stays off. I have not heard of someone doing this in an aftermarket fashion, though.

Comment: Passenger side. We need to do carpool and have a child sit up front.

Comment: While I'm sure you are going to do what you are going to do, I am going to highly suggest you do not ride children in the front seat. With or without air bags, this is not a safe place for them to be. Take it for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **NO**

No reputable shop is going to even consider doing it for you, as it opens you and them up to a major liability.

Unfortunately for you the vehicle was made in the time frame when manufactures hadn't fully dealt with the problem of small adults and children being injured by the airbags. The vehicle is equipped with dual stage airbags, which was one of the first steps but the newer cars turn the airbag off and on depending on who is sitting in the front seat.

Don't put small adults or children in the front seat, but If you **Must**, then move the seat to the rearward most position. And **NEVER put a rear facing child seat in the front seat of a vehicle with an active airbag regardless of seat position.**

Update:

There is a company [AOI Electrical, LLC. A Pro-gard Products Company](http://www.aoielectrical.com/index.asp) that makes the switches and has a network of dealers to sell and install them. You could contact them about putting one in for you. Again I wouldn't, but the option does exist.

Comment: Really? Seems that the NHTSA thinks it's fine under certain circumstances. http://www.safercar.gov/Vehicle+Shoppers/Air+Bags/ON-OFF+Switch+Requests

Comment: @JoeZ We had someone come to our dealership with said letter and our service manager wouldn't even consider it. This was around 2000, the manufacture (GM) at the time did not have an option to do it, and even though it's relatively simple to disable the dealership would not consider it.